# Multiply numpy matrices and get some of the results

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I want to operate with this matrix:

```
(a b)
(c d)
(e f)
```

and get:

```
(a*a+b*b c*c+d*d e*e+f*f)
```

or any matrix, for example:

```
(a b c)
(d e f)
(g h i)
(j k l)
```

and get

```
(a*a+b*b+c*c d*d+e*e+f*f g*g+h*h+i*i j*j+k*k+l*l)
```

How do I make it to work generally with any matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you want the sum of the squares?

Simply do:

```
(a**2).sum(1)
```

example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],
              [ 3,  4,  5],
              [ 6,  7,  8],
              [ 9, 10, 11]])

(a**2).sum(1)
```

output:

```
array([  5,  50, 149, 302])
```